# Continuity of a function on C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the space $C[0,1]$( space of all complex valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$) with the sup norm $\|{\cdot}\|_\infty$.

Now define the function $\Lambda$ on $C[0,1]$ as $\Lambda(f)=f(x_0)$ where $x_0$ is the point where $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ is attained .
Will $\Lambda$ be a continuous function on $(C[0,1], \|{\cdot}\|_\infty)$?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be well-defined, consider $f(x)=2x-1$. Is $\Lambda(f)=1$ or $-1$?

Comment: A better definition will be just $\Lambda(f)=\|f(x)\|_\infty$

Comment: @Adam So what? Suppose the maximum of $|f|$ is $1$, and there are points $x_0, x_1$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x_1)=i$. So what will $\Lambda(f)$ be in this case?

Comment: @Mark good point, maybe $\Lambda$ should be defined to be $\max |f|$

Comment: Well, in that case the statement becomes trivial as every norm is continuous with respect to it self.

Comment: @leoli1 good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, $\Lambda(f)=||f||_{\infty}$, then $\Lambda$ is clearly a sublinear map and also note that $\Lambda(f)=||f||_\infty \implies |\Lambda(f)-\Lambda(g)|=|||f||_{\infty}-||g||_\infty|$ thus it is continuous!